# How to change width of an ImageView in Android SDK

Tags: android, imageview

so I'm trying to learn to do stuff with Android apps, and I have an ImageView named (id) "img_BarHealth" that i initialize to be "160dp".

I have made a button and hooked it up to this function:

```
public void onBack(View view) {
    //Get link to the object.
    ImageView bar_Health = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_BarHealth);

    //This is what I want done. (However this value is not accessable it seems)
    bar_Health.width = "80dp";
}
```

So, any suggestions? =)

Comment: I think it's already here what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144940/set-imageview-width-and-height-programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **getLayoutParams().width**

```
ImageView bar_Health = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_BarHealth);
    bar_Health.getLayoutParams().width = 80;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `getLayoutParams().width` and then you need to convert [dip to pixel size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399184/convert-dip-to-px-in-android):

```
public int convertDipToPixels(float dips)
{
    return (int) (dips * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f);
}
```

Something working would be close to:

```
bar_Health.getLayoutParams().width = convertDipToPixels(80);
```