# How to set padding over imageview of same to all device

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

Hello I am setting padding to the `ImageView` and each device is showing me different padding, somewhere it is less or somewhere it is more.

I am doing this

```
int padding = Util.dpFromPx(6, this);
thumbnailImageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
thumbnailImageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

// convert the px to dp
public static int dpFromPx(float px, Context context) {
    return (int) (px / context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
}
```

I want to keep padding same to all device. Any idea to do that ?

Sony device

[image]

Samsung Dous

[image]

Comment: You should convert dip to pixels like that:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399184/convert-dip-to-px-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SetPadding receive the values in pixels.

So you need to start from dips and convert to pixels:

```
int paddingInPx = Util.dipsToPixels(6);
thumbnailImageView.setPadding(paddingInPx , paddingInPx , paddingInPx , paddingInPx );

public int dipsToPixels(int dips)
    {
        return (dips * getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f);
    }
```